# Refresh with ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on being able to refresh a div that contains data from a database.

I have established this code here but when I open the F12 console, this error appears:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at loadlink (index.php:29:17)
at index.php:34:13**

I have two files an index file and a commands file or on the index file I will include a commands.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="commandes">
     <?php
            $sql = "SELECT enc_id, enc_cmd_num, enc_paye, enc_prepared, enc_ext_ref, enc_heure_fab_deb, enc_type, enc_heure_fab_fin, Client.cli_civilite,Client.cli_nom, Client.cli_prenom FROM Client RIGHT JOIN encaissement ON Client.cli_id = encaissement.enc_client WHERE enc_etat<>4 AND enc_date= convert(date,getdate()) AND ((DATEDIFF(n,enc_heure_fab_fin, getDate()) < 3 AND enc_prepared <> 0) OR enc_prepared = 0) AND enc_emporte <> 1 ORDER BY encaissement.enc_heure_fab_deb ASC";

            $results = odbc_exec( $conn, $sql );
    ?>


<table>
            <?php
                while( $row = odbc_fetch_array( $results ) )
                {
                    printf('<tr>');

                    if ( $row["enc_ext_ref"] != '')
                        {
                            $num_cmd = $row["enc_ext_ref"];
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            $num_cmd =$row["enc_cmd_num"];
                        }


                    if ($row['enc_paye'] = 0)
                    {
                        $etat_cmd='<span class="PRETE">ATTENTE REGLEMENT</span>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch( $row['enc_prepared'] )
                        {
                            case 0: $etat_cmd='<span class="ENPREPA">EN PREPARATION</span>'; break;

                            case 1:
                                $etat_cmd='<span class="PRETE">COMMANDE PRETE</span>'; break;break;
                        }
                    }


                    switch( $row['enc_type'] )
                    {
                        case 0: $commande='<span class="EMPORTER"></span>'; break;

                        case 1: $commande='<span class="LIVRAISON"></span>'; break;

                        case 2: $commande='<span class="SURPLACE"></span>'; break;
                    }



                    printf('<td>%s%s%s</td>',$row["enc_cmd_num"],$etat_cmd, $commande);
               
                }

            ?>



            </table>
        </div>

        <script>
            function loadlink(){
                $('#commandes').load('commandes.php', function() {

                });
            }

            loadlink();
            setInterval(function(){
                loadlink()
            }, 10000);
        </script>
```

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery, but I don't see where you include it? If you didn't know, `$(...).load();` is a jQuery method, not native JS.

Comment: Since you see an error in your browser console, you have a javascript error. Look at the sourcecode as send to your browser (that is NOT your PHP code), find out where the offending line is (nr 29), and see what is going on there. It looks like you are using JQuery, you might want to add that tag to your question.

Comment: @ErwinMoller My line 31 on the browser corresponds to the line of code: $('#commandes').load('commandes.php', function() {
and still displays the same problem with the $

Comment: @SHEYY Are you aware that $ is not valid Javascript? It only works if you use JQuery, as M. Eriksson mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

before `<script>`